# How to give a user the option to select bsckground of a linearlayout from DxsettingsActivity that targets the MainActivity?

Tags: select, sharedpreferences, uri, background-image, onactivityresult

I want the user to be able to go into settings of my app and select from the images provided or select a photo from their internal or external storage to be applied to the background of the `MainActivity`. Also I want this image to stay even after the app has been killed until the user decides to change the background again. I have tried multiple codes and I run into errors every time and the main problem I'm having is sending this intent from one `Activity` to another. I have used code that allow me to apply an image to an `ImageView` within the same `Activity` but I cannot take that code and get it to send across to another `Activity`.

Targets:

```
LinearLayout - backgroundtop (MainActivity)
Imageview(onClick) - gallery (DxsettingsActivity)
Imageview(onClick) - dx (DxsettingsActivity)
```

"`Gallery`" and "`dx`" are in a `customview dialog.`

When "`gallery`" is clicked internal/external storage is opened to select background resource of "`backgroundtop`" and save that image until user changes it again.

When "`dx`" is clicked it opens `DxWallpaperActivity` which will have the images to be selected and saved as the background of "`backgroundtop`".

I hope I have explain well enough. I'll provide more info if needed. Thank you in advance. I have been struggling with this for days to no avail.

Update: I have managed to accomplish setting and saving images from in-app images to the background. I have tried everything under the sun to pull image from gallery and do the same. I have managed to open gallery and select an image but I can't figure out onActivityResult then send that to the background. Please help.

This is the only code I've got to work but it doesn't have shared preferences and it for an imageview. How can I change it for backgroundresource on linearlayout?

```
}

private static final String STATE_IMAGE_URI = 
"STATE_IMAGE_URI";

private Uri imageUri;

public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle state) {

super.onSaveInstanceState(state);
if (imageUri != null ) {
state.putParcelable(STATE_IMAGE_URI, imageUri);
}

}

public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle state) {
super.onRestoreInstanceState(state);
if(state == null || !state.containsKey(STATE_IMAGE_URI)) 
return;

setImage((Uri) state.getParcelable(STATE_IMAGE_URI));

}

private static final int IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE = 9;

private void chooseImage() {

Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setType("image/*");
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, 
"Select picture"), IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE);


}

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int. 
resultCode, Intent data) {

super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
if (requestCode != IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE) {
return;
}

if (resultCode != Activity.RESULT_OK) {
return;
}

setImage(data.getData());

}

private void setImage(Uri uri) {
imageUri = uri;
imageview1.setImageURI(uri);
}



private void nothing() {
```

And for the button clicked

```
chooseImage();
```

Comment: Have you tried getting the URI of the image the user clicks, saving that URI in a sharedpreferences file and using that URI to load the image into an imageview anywhere?

Comment: Yes I have and the problem I'm having is placement. Where is onActivityResult suppose to go? Also, I haven't found exactly what I've needed. I need to be able to open gallery, select an image, that image be applied to background of linearlayout of MainActivity. The action is being done from DxsettingsActivity.

Comment: The image is suppose to be loaded to the background resource not an imageview.